# Running multiple servers on same box?

Tags: apache, server

I was trying to figure out that if i have a box running Apache on it on some port  (Example: - 80) so is it possible that i can run django-server on the same box but different port (Example:- 8000, that is, the port other than Apache ?

thank you for the reply. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's the very purpose of port numbers to offer different services on the same address.

Answer (score 0):

You must not overlap the ports and you can have as many services as you want (as long as have enough resources to run them). You can always check which port is used by which services using netstat -tlpn. netstat command is part of net-tools package.

Best regards.